# Check if Thickbox is open

Tags: javascript, thickbox

I'm using WP and I use the Thickbox to upload images in the back end on a custom page.

Is there a way for JS to check to see if the Thickbox is open?

I need to check this as I have an `onbeforeunload` event (to show a warning when the user leaves the page, in certain situations), but obviously Idon't want the warning shown when the user is just navigating between Thickbox pages. Thanks.

Code I currently use -

```
var bol_submit_clicked = false;
$('input[name="Submit"]').click(function(){
    bol_submit_clicked = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function closeEditorWarning(){

    var bol_option_changed = false;

    /** Check to see if the settings warning is displayed */
    if($('#unsaved-settings').css('display') !== 'none'){
        bol_option_changed = true;
    }

    /** Display a warning if the user is trying to leave the page with unsaved settings */
    if(bol_option_changed === true && bol_submit_clicked === false){
        return '';
    }


};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no inherent function in Thickbox to check, but looking at the code, you should just be able to check for the presence and visibility of `#TB_window`:

```
var thickbox_shown = ($('#TB_window').is(':visible')) ? true : false;
```

Or, try counting the length of `#TB_load`:

```
var thickbox_shown = ($('#TB_load').length > 0) ? true : false;\
```

Comment: I llike the thouht, but it is sadly not working. No errors, it's just returning `false` even when the Thickbox is open. `#TB_window` exists at this point, so not sure what's going on...

Comment: Very odd. The code definitely works in terms of the principle: http://jsfiddle.net/nnFtu/

Comment: Ok, I'll update on my above comment; When I am in the Thickbox and either change page or click 'Save all changes', the above code returns `false`. However, if I refresh the page (F5), I first see `true` returned, followed swiftly by `false`. I'm a little stumped as to what could be going on here...

Comment: p.s. I get the same results when using `length > 0` as well. I'm confident that your solution is solid, but I don't know why it is not working as intended. Could it be that `window.onbeforeunload()` will not acknowledge the Thickbox, because it is an iframe?

Comment: So I've got a solution to this - I changed my code to check to see if the 'settings warning' was displayed to mirror your suggested code for seeing if the Thickbox was displayed, using `.is(:visible)`, and it now seems to work. Thanks for the help yesterday.